# In Java using passing an array of sub-classes as their parents

Tags: java, arrays, list, sorting, inheritance

I have a simulation with three classes: `Entities`, `Plants` and `Animals` (plants and animals `extends` entities).

I want one method to be able to sort the three arrays, the elements in the array all inherit from the same class.

Is there a way to pass all of the arrays to a method as their parent classes.

I am calling:

```
sortEntityArray(AnimalList);
```

From:

```
void sortEntityArray(ArrayList<Entity> ListToSort) {
        boolean sorted = false;
        while (sorted == false) {
            sorted = true;
            for (int i1 = 0; i1 < ListToSort.size() - 1; i1++) {
                if (ListToSort.get(i1).PositionX < ListToSort.get(i1 + 1).PositionX) {
                    sorted = false;
                    //switch
                    Entity Temp = ListToSort.get(i1);
                    ListToSort.set(i1, ListToSort.get(i1 + 1));
                    ListToSort.set(i1, Temp);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

When I try to pass I get this error:
 `The method sortEntityArray(ArrayList<Entity>) in the type World is not applicable for the arguments (ArrayList<Animal>)`

Comment: Please edit your question with the applicable code that generates the error and also include the full error.

Comment: You got an answer, but I would recommend to use `List` instead of `ArrayList` as argument type. You gain nothing from being too specific here, you just lose the flexibility to work with different `List` implementations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way to pass all of the arrays to a method as their parent classes?

Yes, if you pass `ArrayList<Entity>` you will be able to work with all 3 types since they `extend` the same parent class.

I would try changing the method's signature to:

```
void sortEntityArray(ArrayList<? extends Entity> ListToSort)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just use the java .sort function, this will work on any array.

Comment: OP will need to make `Entities implements Comparable` in order to make this work.